# How would I randomly assign 4 textboxes text from my list? And have one of those randomly match up with a variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, function, variables

Currently, on code.org, I have a project where you need to guess a dinosaur fossil from a list of them. What I have envisioned is to be given 4 options and a picture, however I don't know how to make sure that one of the buttons randomly gets the correct answer, while the other 3 random ones get random names from the list. I have the code that selections the specific variable/correct answer.

`var dinosaur = ["T-Rex", "Velociraptor", "Allosaurus", "Spinosaurus", "Brachiosaurus", "Stegosaurus", "Ankylosaurus", "Triceratops", "Parasaurolophus", "Iguanodon", "Diplodocus", "Argentinosaurus", "Isanosaurus", "Styracosaurus", "Baryonyx", "Carnotaurus", "Europasaurus"];`

````
onEvent("Next", "click", function(nextDinosaur) {
  var dino = dinoPick(dinosaur);
  console.log(dino);
});
function dinoPick(list){
    return (list[(randomNumber(0,list.length-1))]);
}```
````

Comment: 1. copy the array 2. put the correct answer in a new array, removing it from the copy 3. pick a random element and also move it over, repeat two times 4. you now have an array containing the correct answer, followed by three false ones; all you need to do is shuffle it - - - you could also randomly remove wrong answer elements from the array until its length is four, then shuffle it.

Comment: I wont lie to you, this kind of made it more confusing for me lol- does that mean I would need 4 arrays? and one will feed the right answer to a random button/textbox? Also, the shuffling is the part that I completely do not understand and is what I am most confused by

Comment: You only have to create a copy of the `dinosaur` array if you want to keep the original to generate the next question. In addition, you need a third, empty array that gets filled with the four answers. Shuffling an array is simple: just google "js shuffle array" ;)

Comment: I did step 1, I understand 100%- I don't understand #2 one bit, would I just leave it in its own array as a single one? I made an empty array and that one randomly gets 4 outputs, with 0 ideas on how to select which should be the answer(I was thinking I would do a math.random to select it but then I would need to somehow make sure the image correlates) I don't understand what #3 is asking for at all, and I am learning shuffling right now :)

Comment: `onEvent("Next", "click", function(nextDinosaur) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var dinos = dinoPick(dinosaur2);
    appendItem(dinoChoice, dinos);
    console.log(dinoChoice);
  }
});`
dinosaur2 is the copy, dinoChoice is the empty list

Comment: Here's a solution: https://jsfiddle.net/2hjmsvfk/

Comment: i partially understand, gonna try to convert it to what the website knows how to use lets see how that goes lmao- Thank you!!

Comment: @JovanyV please check my simple solution below which introduces new `pickRand()` `Array.prototype/Object.prototype` methods that return a certain number of custom elements/properties from an array/object. This makes this task very simple. Also, see my full app solution below that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

In my full solution further down, I wrote two prototype functions that return a certain number of elements/properties (defaults to return 1 element/property) at random and return those value(s). For this TL;DR version of the solution, you only need the array function I wrote.

This should do what you are looking for:

```js
const dinosaur = ['T-Rex', 'Velociraptor', 'Allosaurus', 'Spinosaurus', 'Brachiosaurus', 'Stegosaurus', 'Ankylosaurus', 'Triceratops', 'Parasaurolophus', 'Iguanodon', 'Diplodocus', 'Argentinosaurus', 'Isanosaurus', 'Styracosaurus', 'Baryonyx', 'Carnotaurus', 'Europasaurus'];

Array.prototype.pickRand = function(count = 1, copy) { return ((copy = [...this]), (count = Math.min(copy.length, count)), Array(count).fill().map(x => copy.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length),1)[0])); }

let options = dinosaur.pickRand(4);
let correct = options.pickRand();

console.log(`The four options are ${options.map((e,i) => !i ? `and ${e}` : e).reverse().join(', ')}.\n\nThe correct option is ${correct}.`)
```

### The full solution with details and a working app ✨

I wrote up a prototype function called `pickRand()` with methods to support both arrays and objects and essentially picks a random number of items or properties from the array/object. To accomplish your task, I turned your array of options into a key-value object where the unique keys are the species and the values are the images associated with each.

```js
const options = dinosaur.pickRand(4);
const correctSpecies = Object.keys(options.pickRand())[0];
```

As I programmed this, one key focus I had was to make this secure in such a way where if someone answering the questions were to look at the console, there would be no simple or obvious way of seeing which option presented is the correct answer. To do this, I incorporated simple MD5 hashing by pulling in an external library. I pick 4 random options from the object and iterate through them, picking one of them randomly as the correct answer. As I iterate over the correct answer, I hash its ID and set it as a data-attribute value on the parent form, and I also set the question's image URL to the value of its `imageURL` property.

```js
const options = dinosaur.pickRand(4);
const correctSpecies = Object.keys(options.pickRand())[0]; // -> "T-Rex"
Object.entries(options).forEach(([species, imageURL]) => {
    const speciesKey = keyify(species);
    // ...
    if (species === correctSpecies) {
        form.dataset.hash = md5(speciesKey);
        questionImage.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageURL})`;
    }
});
```

Then, when someone clicks an answer, I compare the hashed ID of their selected answer with the hash value we previously stored in the form's data-attribute. If they are equal, we mark the answer as correct via a data-attribute on the input's associated label. Otherwise, we mark it as incorrect. This "correct status" affects styling as well as verbiage in the button to generate a new question.

Here it is, all put together. Click "Run Snippet" below to see the quiz in action. For the sake of this example, I am using placeholder images with the correct answer's text for each so you can easily test true and false values.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('questions');

var dinosaur = {
    'T-Rex': 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/6d4c41/efebe9/?text=T-Rex',
    'Velociraptor': 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/6d4c41/efebe9/?text=Velociraptor',
    'Allosaurus': 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/6d4c41/efebe9/?text=Allosaurus',
    'Spinosaurus': 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/6d4c41/efebe9/?text=Spinosaurus',
    'Brachiosaurus': 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/6d4c41/efebe9/?text=Brachiosaurus',
    'Stegosaurus': 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/6d4c41/efebe9/?text=Stegosaurus',
    'Ankylosaurus': 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/6d4c41/efebe9/?text=Ankylosaurus',
    'Triceratops': 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/6d4c41/efebe9/?text=Triceratops',
    'Parasaurolophus': 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/6d4c41/efebe9/?text=Parasaurolophus',
    'Iguanodon': 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/6d4c41/efebe9/?text=Iguanodon',
    'Diplodocus': 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/6d4c41/efebe9/?text=Diplodocus',
    'Argentinosaurus': 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/6d4c41/efebe9/?text=Argentinosaurus',
    'Isanosaurus': 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/6d4c41/efebe9/?text=Isanosaurus',
    'Styracosaurus': 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/6d4c41/efebe9/?text=Styracosaurus',
    'Baryonyx': 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/6d4c41/efebe9/?text=Baryonyx',
    'Carnotaurus': 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/6d4c41/efebe9/?text=Carnotaurus',
    'Europasaurus': 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/6d4c41/efebe9/?text=Europasaurus'
};

Array.prototype.pickRand = function(count = 1, copy) { return ((copy = [...this]), (count = Math.min(copy.length, count)), Array(count).fill().map(x => copy.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length),1)[0])); }

Object.prototype.pickRand = function(count = 1, copy) { return ((copy = Object.entries({...this})), (count = Math.min(copy.length, count)), Object.fromEntries(Array(count).fill().map(x => copy.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length),1)[0]))); }

const keyify = term => term.toLowerCase().replace(/[-\s]/g, '');

const generateQuestion = () => {
    const options = dinosaur.pickRand(4);
    const correctSpecies = Object.keys(options.pickRand(1))[0];
    form.innerHTML = '';
    form.dataset.hash = '';
    form.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<div id="question-image"></div>`);
    const questionImage = form.querySelector('#question-image');
    Object.entries(options).forEach(([species, imageURL]) => {
        const speciesKey = keyify(species);
        form.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<input type="radio" name="dinosaur" value="${speciesKey}" id="${speciesKey}" required><label for="${speciesKey}">${species}</label>`);
        if (species === correctSpecies) {
            form.dataset.hash = md5(speciesKey);
            questionImage.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageURL})`;
        }
    });
};

const validateAnswer = () => {
    const inputs = Array.from(form.querySelectorAll('input'));
    const selected = inputs.filter(e => e.checked)[0];
    const correctStatus = md5(selected.id) === form.dataset.hash;
    inputs.forEach(input => input.disabled = true);
    selected.nextElementSibling.setAttribute('data-correct', correctStatus);
    form.dataset.hash = '';
    form.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<button class="${correctStatus ? 'correct' : 'incorrect'}">${correctStatus ? 'Great job! Next question' : 'Try again'}</button>`);
};

document.addEventListener('click', e => e.target?.matches('form button') && generateQuestion());

document.addEventListener('change', e => e.target?.matches('form input') && validateAnswer());

form.addEventListener('submit', e => e.preventDefault());

generateQuestion();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500&display=swap');
@charset "UTF-8";
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #37474f;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
#questions {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-self: flex-start;
}
#questions > :nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#question-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  align-self: center;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
input + label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #eceff1;
  border-radius: 500px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
}
input + label::after {
  content: "";
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px rgba(55, 71, 79, 0.25);
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #fff;
  transition: inherit;
}
input + label[data-correct] {
  font-weight: 500;
}
input + label[data-correct=false] {
  background-color: #ffcdd2;
  color: #b71c1c;
}
input + label[data-correct=false]::after {
  content: "";
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 16px #f44336;
}
input + label[data-correct=true] {
  background-color: #c8e6c9;
  color: #1b5e20;
}
input + label[data-correct=true]::after {
  content: "";
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 16px #4caf50;
}
button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #2196f3;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 500px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button::after {
  content: "";
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
}
button:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-md5/2.18.0/js/md5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/07afc061fe.js"></script>
<form id="questions" data-hash=""></form>
```

One possible improvement I see here is splicing values from the original object as the user guesses questions correctly so they aren't quizzed on the same question again once they answer it correctly. This way, the user will keep answering until they guess all questions correctly. When there are too few choices left from the number of options left, we can fall back to using random items that were already guessed to fill in the gaps until every option is correctly selected.

Comment: wow! thank you so much, this mostly answered most of my questions then, is there a way to close this now that it's answered?

Comment: @JovanyVGlad I could help. Questions can't be "closed" to my knowledge, but if you accept my solution as your chosen answer, that's about the closest equivalent here.

Comment: @JovanyV I'm working on a few improvements in my spare time. When I get those done, I'll be sure to add the new version to my previous answer. I've added the security benefit of writing the image to a `<canvas>` element so the actual URL of the image can't be inspected, I've added CSS custom properties to keep track of how many questions you have left (using a custom CSS pseudo-element progress bar), and a results screen at the end with the score and an option to play again, preloading all images for performance, and adding a new `Bind()` object that keeps all variables in sync. Stay tuned!