# How do I adjust the code so that the image appears when the website loads and the guess is guessing what I want it to guess?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, loops, if-statement

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="Image"></p>
```

Basically what im tryijngto do s

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove the extra white space. You could also help others out by using Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to produce a [mre] that can be run in the question.

Comment: Your question is very similar to another I answered a few days ago: [How would I randomly assign 4 textboxes text from my list? And have one of those randomly match up with a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67192069/3824249)

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell no sorry that doesnt

Comment: @Chad1212323232 in what ways does it differ? My solution takes a list of options and their associated images from an array, randomly picks a number of them, displays those options with one correct option. If the user selects the correct value, it marks it correct and tracks their progress. At the end of the game, it displays their results.

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell I see but im not trying to do the same thing. Im not having trouble with selecting the random image. My problem currently is that when I run the page I just want the image to show up already. Im not very good at coding, so its kind of hard to explain. Can you run my code so that you can see what I mean? I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Chad1212323232 I've added my own solution as well which adds some room for greater flexibility. Let me know what kinds of parameters you were looking to add.

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell Thank you so much for your help. What kind of parameter do you think would work with my code. i'm not exactly sure what I wanna make a parameter for. Thank you

Comment: @Chad1212323232 well what else would you like my solution to do that it doesn’t already?

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is a working version of your game. To begin: <br>
1.Your code was not modifying the src of the image (thus no image appears) <br>
1a. I am modifying the src attribute associated with the `img` tag now. <br>
1b. `document.getElementById("Image").src = randomPhoto;` <br>
2. `theArrayArray` does not exist. I updated the variable to `theArray` <br>
3. To display an image when the game begins you need a handler. <br>
3a. I added the `button` to handle that <br>
4. Unless you want the user to type out `.jpg` you need to remove .jpg <br>
4a. `randomPhoto = randomPhoto.replace(".jpg", "");` <br>


   

     <img id="Image" src="#" width="250" height="250">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input id="userInput" type="text">
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="startGame()">Start Game</button>
        <span id="GameScore">Score:</span> 
    
    
        <script>
          
          let score = 10;
          var Chad = "Chad.jpg";
        
          let begin = 1;
          let thePhoto;
          var someArray = [ Chad, Bob
];
          function startGame() {
            if (start == 0) {
              for (var l = 2; i < 3; i--) {
                randomPhoto = theArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*theArray.length)];
                document.getElementById("Image").src = randomPhoto;
                document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = "Submit";
                start = 1;
              }
            } else {
    
    
              
              randomPhoto = randomPhoto.replace(".jpg", "Insert");
                
                 }
                else {
    for (var x = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                  TheName = theArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*theArray.length)];
                  document.getElementById("Image").src = theName;
                  alert("No");
                  scorex = score-1;
                }
                document.getElementById("theScore").innerHTML="Score: "+score;
    
               
          
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: @J Code Thank you so much! Is there anywhere in here that you think I can insert parameters into?

Comment: What would you want to insert parameters for?

Comment: @J Code is there a way for you to update your answer so that this is with numbers? I want to make the exact same game but for numbers. So basically the number between 1-10 shows up, and the user has to write in the text box what the number is. Im still a little bit confused.

Comment: To do this you would just represent the images using numbers. You could use objects to associate the image with a number.

Comment: @J Code Thank you so much for your help man. But I don't mean associating an image with a number. I mean how do I solely make it so that the person is writing the number on the screen that they see? Like for example if the number 5 comes up in the array that I set the person has to write 5. If you know how to do this could you please help me by updating the code?

Answer (score 0):

One fix I'd recommend would be splitting your logic into two functions, one the user clicks to check their answer, and one they click to see the next question. This will allow you to display the congrats message on the screen rather than in an alert. Here is that in action:

```js
let score = 0;
let questionsAsked = 0;
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const input = document.getElementById('userInput');
const gameScore = document.getElementById('game-score-inner');
gameScore.add = (pts = 1) => gameScore.innerHTML = parseInt(gameScore.textContent) + 1;
gameScore.subtract = (pts = 1) => gameScore.innerHTML = Math.max(parseInt(gameScore.textContent) - 1, 0);
const checkMessage = document.getElementById('check-message');
checkMessage.set = message => checkMessage.innerHTML = message;
checkMessage.clear = message => checkMessage.innerHTML = '';
const options = {
  chad: 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/000000/efebe9/?text=Chad',
  bob: 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/000000/efebe9/?text=Bob',
  john: 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400/000000/efebe9/?text=John'
}
function askQuestion() {
  checkMessage.clear();
  input.value = '';
  const optionsNames = Object.values(options);
  const randomPhoto = optionsNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * optionsNames.length)];
  document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = `<img src="${randomPhoto}" id="question-image" width="250" height="250" />`;
  button.setAttribute('onclick','checkAnswer()');
  button.textContent = 'Check Your Answer!';
}
function checkAnswer() {
  const userGuess = options[input.value.toLowerCase()];
  const correctAnswer = document.getElementById('question-image').getAttribute('src');
  if (options[input.value.toLowerCase()] === correctAnswer) {
    checkMessage.set('CONGRATULATIONS!!! YOU GUESSED IT RIGHT');
    gameScore.add();
  } else {
    checkMessage.set('SORRY, IT WAS INCORRECT');
    gameScore.subtract();
  }
  questionsAsked++;
  button.setAttribute('onclick','askQuestion()');
  button.textContent = 'Next Question';
}
askQuestion();
```

```html
<p id="image"></p>
<p id="game-score">Score: <span id="game-score-inner">0</span></p>
<button onclick="checkAnswer()">Start Game!</button>
<input id="userInput" type="text" />
<p id="check-message"></p>
```

If you would prefer to keep everything in one function and use alerts for the congrats message, you can do so by keeping track of then number of questions asked, and not instantly checking the answer on the first load, like this:

```js
let score = 0;
let questionsAnswered = -1;
const imageContainer = document.getElementById('image');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const input = document.getElementById('user-input');
const gameScore = document.getElementById('game-score-inner');
gameScore.add = (pts = 1) => gameScore.innerHTML = parseInt(gameScore.textContent) + 1;
gameScore.subtract = (pts = 1) => gameScore.innerHTML = Math.max(parseInt(gameScore.textContent) - 1, 0);
const options = {
  chad: 'https://via.placeholder.com/250x250/000000/efebe9/?text=Chad',
  bob: 'https://via.placeholder.com/250x250/000000/efebe9/?text=Bob',
  john: 'https://via.placeholder.com/250x250/000000/efebe9/?text=John'
}
function askQuestion() {
  questionsAnswered++;
  const optionsNames = Object.values(options);
  const randomPhoto = optionsNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * optionsNames.length)];
  if (questionsAnswered) {
    const userGuess = options[input.value.toLowerCase()];
    const correctAnswer = document.getElementById('question-image').getAttribute('src');
    if (options[input.value.toLowerCase()] === correctAnswer) {
      gameScore.add();
      alert('CONGRATULATIONS!!! YOU GUESSED IT RIGHT');
    } else {
      gameScore.subtract();
      alert('SORRY, IT WAS INCORRECT');
    }
    questionsAnswered++;
  }
  imageContainer.innerHTML = `<img src="${randomPhoto}" id="question-image" width="250" height="250" />`;
  input.value = '';
}
askQuestion();
```

```html
<p id="image"></p>
<p id="game-score">Score: <span id="game-score-inner">0</span></p>
<button onclick="askQuestion()">Check Answer!</button>
<input id="user-input" type="text" />
```

Both solutions would work fine with alerts, though the first solution offers some greater flexibility for any functions you make want to perform in between questions. One other main fix there was to make here was to check change the image **after** checking the answer, and also making sure to actually fun the function in the beginning using `askQuestion()` in this case. I also added a couple of handy functions `gameScore.add()` and `gameScore.subtract()` to ease future use.

You can pass in other integers such as `gameScore.add(2)` if you every wanted to have double-weighted questions. I also added a `Math.max()` line to ensure the score never passes below 0. You can remove this if you would like the player's score to pass into negative numbers.

Comment: Excellent answer! Hope to cross paths again.